# Creating multiple CSV file using Super CSV

Tags: java

Can we create multiple file based on column value using super-csv.

For example this is my csv file:

```
Name,age,city
TestA,18,Mumbai
TestB, 60, Chennai
TestC,17,Mumbai
```

Here I need to create 2 CSV file on is based on Mumbai and other Chennai.
Can we do that using super-csv i checked
https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/writers.html
But no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you interested in that api particularly?

Comment: To get the work done.